# Show that max $\frac{1}{\lVert w \rVert}$ is the same as min $\frac{1}{2}w^{T}w$

Tags: linear-algebra

In my lecture slide this happens

[image]

I don't understand how the max $\frac{1}{\lVert w \rVert}$ is the same as min $\frac{1}{2}w^{T}w$. I know that taking the max $f(x)$ is equivalent to min $-f(x)$, but does not seem to be the approach taken in this case. In addition, does the min $|w^{T}x_{n} - b | = 1$ mean finding the smallest $x_n$ such that $|w^{T}x_{n} - b | = 1$ holds?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: they are not the same, but the *solutions* to both problems are the same.

Comment: can you prove that?

Comment: the $w$ that maximises $w^Tw$ and the one that minimises $1/\|w\|$ are the same.